# What is that item's rarity in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I just found this weapon in a build in challenge rifts and I don't understand what is the rarity of this weapon. Is it legendary? And how do you get one of those?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is legendary weapon. ([source](https://us.diablo3.blizzard.com/en-us/item/the-spider-queens-grasp-Unique_CeremonialDagger_004_x1))

I wondered why you were asking this (because it is obviously a legendary weapon), and I came up with this conclusion... The reason that your weapon's name and frame is white, is that your weapon is [Sanctified](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Sanctified_Items).

> Sanctified Items are items in Diablo III that have been reforged to have perfect Ancient-level stats on all affixes while also preserving the item's Legendary Power. They are a Season 27 (patch 2.7.4) exclusive.

Sanctified items can be obtained through reforging with [Angelic Crucible](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Angelic_Crucible).

> Angelic Crucibles are Season-exclusive consumable items in Diablo III, Season 27.

It works like [Ramaladni's Gift](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Ramaladni%27s_Gift), which gives a socket to your weapon. I don't know how to use these items on Switch edition, but in PC, right click Ramaladni's gift or Angelic Crucible, then click on the weapon (if Angelic Crucible, any items) to socket/sanctify it.